# Autocompletion for Makefile rules in tcsh

Tags: shell, autocomplete, make, tcsh

I'm using `tcsh` in a SUSE 11 box and I realized that when typing

`make`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

it allows me to auto-complete the rules available within the Makefile, not the files that are inside the current directory.

I've tested this with RedHat and Ubuntu at work and Debian at home (all with `tcsh`), and none of them supports this (IMO) nice behavior.

How can this be achieved with the other distributions as well?
This is something I've wanted to have since many years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add calls to `complete` to your shell startup file (`~/.tcshrc`). Apparently your SuSE box has predefined rules for `make`; look for them in `/etc/csh.cshrc` or some other file provided alongside tcsh (`rpm -ql tcsh`).

The tcsh distribution comes with some example completions (Debian puts them in `/usr/share/doc/tcsh/examples/complete.tcsh.gz`); here's the one for `make`:

```
complete make \
    'n/-f/f/' \
    'c/*=/f/' \
    'n@*@`cat -s GNUmakefile Makefile makefile |& sed -n -e "/No such file/d" -e "/^[^     #].*:/s/:.*//p"`@'
```

Comment: Thanks again @Gilles, "sourcing" that file in Debian gives me immediately auto-completion for `make`

Comment: I tried this under Mac OS but get the following result: `make \`cat -s GNUmakefile Makefile makefile |& sed -n -e "/No such file/d" -e "/^[^     #].*:/s/:.*//p"\`: No match.`

Answer (score 1):

Using [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9524878/923794) to use `make` itself to calculate all the available targets and merging this into the Debian example script as shown in [the other answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32153/28585) and then adding some more, this yields:

```
alias complete_make_target_filter 'awk -F: '"'"'/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^\$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'"'"

complete make \
    'n/--assume-old/f/' \
    'n/--assume-new/f/' \
    'n/--directory/d/' \
    'n/--file/f/' \
    'n/--include-dir/d/' \
    'n/--makefile/f/' \
    'n/--new-file/f/' \
    'n/--old-file/f/' \
    'n/--what-if/f/' \
    'n/-d/d/' \
    'n/-f/f/' \
    'c/*=/f/' \
    'n@*@`make -qp  |& grep -v Stop |complete_make_target_filter|xargs echo --always-make --directory -d --debug -e --environment-overrides --file --makefile -i --ignore-errors -I --include-dir -j --jobs -k --keep-going -l --load-average --max-load -L --check-symlink-times -n --just-print --dry-run --recon -o --old-file --assume-old -p --print-database -q --question -r --no-builtin-rules -R --no-builtin-variables -s --silent --quiet -S --no-keep-going --stop -t --touch -v --version -w --print-directory --no-print-directory -W --what-if --new-file --assume-new --warn-undefined-variables`@'
```

Put this along with other nifty completion scripts into a `~/.complete/` directory and then source them all in your `~/.cshrc` and you're all set.