# Unable to autocomplete ONLY when typing a make command

Tags: bash, autocomplete, make

I'm running Ubuntu Linux 10.04.

And I have the following in my .bashrc file:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

I'm having a problem with autocomplete only when I type:

make  <kbd>Tab</kbd>

For some reason it freezes and the only way to get out of that is to send a keyboard interrupt.  The weird thing is I don't have any problems with autocomplete when executing any other programs...

My question is there a specific reason for this? And is there a way to specifically change the autocomplete instructions for make?

I looked at this question [Autocompletion for Makefile rules in tcsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32017/autocompletion-for-makefile-rules-in-tcsh), but wasn't able to find the tcsh files anywhere on my system.

This is the result from set-x and make <kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
make + local file makef makef_dir=. makef_inc cur prev i split=false
+ COMPREPLY=()
++ _get_cword
++ '[' -n '4.1.5(1)-release' ']'
++ __get_cword4
++ local i
++ local LC_CTYPE=C
++ local 'WORDBREAKS=   
"'\''><=;|&(:'
++ WORDBREAKS='     
'\''><=;|&(:'
++ WORDBREAKS='     
><=;|&(:'
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ local 'cur=make '
++ local 'tmp=make '
+++ expr 'make ' : '.*[     
><=;|&(:]'
++ local word_start=5
++ '[' 5 -ge 2 ']'
++ local char=e
++ '[' e '!=' '\' ']'
++ break
++ cur=
++ printf %s ''
+ cur=
+ prev=make
+ _split_longopt
+ [[ '' == --?*=* ]]
+ return 1
+ case $prev in
+ false
+ [[ '' == -* ]]
+ (( i=0 ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ [[ make == -C ]]
+ (( i++  ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ [[ '' == -C ]]
+ (( i++  ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ (( i=0 ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ [[ make == -f ]]
+ (( i++  ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ [[ '' == -f ]]
+ (( i++  ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n . ']'
+ makef_dir='-C .'
+ COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( make -qp $makef $makef_dir 2>/dev/null      |              awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/     \
            {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' )"             --     "$cur" ))
+++ make -qp -C .
+++ awk -F: '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ \
        {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'
```

Comment: what shell are you using? if you don't know run `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Bash allows for command-specific completion (that's what /etc/bash_completion sets up). It looks like there's something wrong with your rules for `make` (which might be stored in /etc/bash_completion.d/make; I'm not sure about Ubuntu).

Comment: Does this happen even in a directory where there is no Makefile? Run `set -x` in a bash window, then try a completion for `make`, and copy-paste what appears in the shell window.

Comment: echo $SHELL says /bin/bash

@Gilles It's pretty long, should I paste it in my question instead? Or just dump it here in the comments?

Comment: @ishikun Edit your question, or if it's really too long, put it up on [pastebin](http://pastbin.com/).

Comment: @Gilles Alright :). I pasted it in the question